# How does iterable work?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, iterator, deque

Hey guys I've been teaching myself java and I working on this assignment. 
http://ljing.org/games/focus/

So I write a Linked list from scratch, I write a Deque class using the LinkedList class
But!

There's only one question I don't understand about the classes Iterator. 
I just don't understand what does the Class Deque Iterator is supposed to do.

Also, I have this in my code:

```
class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item>.
```

But then the compiler complains that in my Deque class I need to override a method

```
@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator()
{
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

But I don't understand why

Comment: When you `implements` an interface you have to implement it's methods.  Can you clarify your doubt in this regard?  The `iteratior()` should return a new iterator each time you call it.

Comment: You have to create an instance that implements `Iterator<Item>` and return it in the iterator() method.

Comment: An interface is a `contract`, that specifies some methods and their behavior. In order to *implement* an interface, your class must bind to that contract, and provide those method that should work as expected.

Comment: So what would be the point of creating the class Deque Iteraror? is it because I will create an instance of it inside the method iterator()  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An iterator is a concept for accessing the elements in a collection. Because you say `implements Iterable<Item>`, you tell the compiler that you provide this mechanism of accessing the elements of your Deque. But that's not enough yet. Besides claiming you will do it, you actually have to do it. In this case, doing it is implementing the method.

What happens if you don't:

Because you told the compiler you would provide this, you have to implement the method `iterator()`, which is part of this access concept. If you do not implement the method, the compiler complains and tells you "hey, you said you would do it. So keep your word!".

There are two ways to solve this:

1.) In the first place, don't give your word you would provide the access concept through an iterator - remove `implements Iterable<Item>`

2.) Keep your word and implement the method. You will have to write an own Iterator class for this. That's a rather short task once you know what to do.

Comment: So the point of creating the class Deque Iteraror is  because I will create an instance of it inside the method iterator() ?

Comment: Yes. But the Deque class is not the end purpose. The purpose is that later when you make use of your Deque class in some other code, you can use the iterator concept for accessing the elements in the Deque. That makes it simpler to write the code which uses the Deque class. Something like moving code complexity from one code part to another code part, or said better, from one level of abstraction to another one. Find example code using collection classes with iterators and you will understand it better, e.g. the first two at http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-iterator/

Comment: Got it thanks dude. If you have any examples can you link me? Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

There are two different interfaces in Java for iteration that are important, [`Iterable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) and [`Iterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html). They each serve a different purpose.

**Iterable**

When something implements this interface, this means that it can be iterated on. This is useful for us because Java gives us a shortcut for iterating over things that implement `Iterable` using a for-each loop:

```
List<String> elements = ... ; // List is an instance of Iterable
for (String element : elements)
    System.out.println(element);
```

Anything that is an instance of `Iterable` can be used in a for-each loop. If you have your own custom `MyDeque` class that implements `Iterable`, then you can use that in a for-each as well:

```
MyDeque<String> elements = ... ;
for (String element : elements)
    System.out.println(element);
```

This brings us to...

**Iterator**

This interface is how the iteration is actually performed. The for-each loop compiles to something like this:

```
MyDeque<String> elements = ... ;
for (Iterator<String> $iter = elements.iterator(); $iter.hasNext();) {
    String element = $iter.next();
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

This piece of code is functionally equivalent to the for-each above. `hasNext()` is the continuation condition (do I have more stuff to give you?) and `next()` actually gives you the next element, or throws a `NoSuchElementException` if we don't have anything else.

The point of making your custom deque implement `Iterable` is just to make it so you can iterate over the elements in your deque using something like a `for` loop. Its `Iterator` implementation is the thing that will let you actually *do* that iteration.